# How to prevent the app from being "minimized" by AppSwitch Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to lock the device for one application only.

I use in my project a line that determines that my app becomes a `launcher`. So, the initial screen of the device is my application and the `HomeButton` ends up always pointing to the application. Line below.

```
[IntentFilter (new [] {Intent.ActionMain}, Categories = new [] {Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault})]
```

I was able to lock the buttons to prevent the user from accessing the device settings by changing the * .kl files inside the /system/usr/keylayout folder. But the only way to do this is with the rooted device. I'm looking for ways not to need to roote the device.

The `BackButton`, I get "lock" on the device inside my application, using the `public override void OnBackPressed()`.

The volume buttons I can "lock" on the device using the code below.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown (Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
        case Android.Views.Keycode.VolumeUp:
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Volume Up pressed", ToastLength.Long) .Show ();
            e.Dispose ();
            return true;
        case Android.Views.Keycode.VolumeDown:
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Volume Down pressed", ToastLength.Long) .Show ();
            e.Dispose ();
            OnUserLeaveHint ();
            return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown (keyCode, e);
}
```

***However, the only button I can not "block" is `AppSwitch`, which is the easiest way to access settings.***

I tried with the code that follows, but without success.

```
protected override void OnPause ()
{
    base.OnPause ();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) GetSystemService (Activity.ActivityService);
    activityManager.MoveTaskToFront (TaskId, 0);
}
```

The taskbar I do the lock also. But only within the application.

I also read about `AccessibilityService`, where we can change creating a Hook on the buttons pressed. But I did not get much information and the tests I did were unsuccessful.

Any idea how to block?

Comment: You are probably looking for the Android Management API: https://developers.google.com/android/management/